# Adverb fascinated (deeply or extremely)

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I am currently working on my essay and I am not too sure whether deeply or extremely fascinated is correct.
It would be nice if somebody explained this to me because I think these two adverbs sound perfectly fine since they both mean or elucidate the same.

To clarify my problem, here's the sentence:

> ...And hence, I am (deeply/extremely) fascinated by Musk's career and personality.

Comment: They are both *correct*. I doubt that anybody would be confused by what you're trying to express, regardless of the specific word you choose, (You could also use *very* or *quite*.) Unless there is a subtle difference you're trying to convey, which is better expressed by one than the other, then it doesn't matter. Simply pick whichever sounds best to you.

Comment: Hi Celine, welcome to EL&U. I'm afraid I need to flag this question for closure as "proofreading" ("Is this correct?" "Which word is best?"). As Jason notes, both usages are correct, and both are common, so it's really up to you which to use and therefore there's no "correct answer" to your question - although the answer you've already received may be useful for you. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: PS Celine, if you have other questions about *writing* (rather than this one about *specific wording*), you might find our other site [Writing.SE] worth a visit. That site covers all kinds of writing - fiction, poetry, essays, technical books, other non-fiction. And depending on what your essay is about, there might even be a Stack Exchange specifically for that topic, e.g. [Literature.SE]. :-)

Comment: It may help to remember that *deeply* **has degree**, *extremely* doesn't -- it's absolute.

Answer (score -1):

Both of those words work fine as [intensifiers](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/intensifiers-very-at-all) for the verb "fascinate". They carry the same general connotation when used that way, and both have proper levels of formality for an essay. The choice is purely aesthetic, use whichever you think sounds better.

In general, intensifiers do not carry vital meaning. They exist to emphasize the verb, which carries the meaning. You can almost always substitute a intensifier with "very" and at worst sound only a little odd, but you won't lose any meaning. For example, you could say "I am very fascinated by Musks's career and personality," and it still makes perfect sense grammatically and logically, it's just lacking in flair.

Comment: -1 "In general, intensifiers do not carry vital meaning." They are not even intensifiers *per se*. -- Please see my comment at OP.